# Turn differential equation with $\sin$ into system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I just had this problem in my differential equations exam;
it started with: Turn this differential equation into a system  of first order then find its equilibria and classify them + Lyapunov question
$$x''(t)+2\alpha x'(t)+\alpha^2\sin (x(t))=0$$

The problem was I could't get rid of the $\sin(x)$ so I said for $\sin(x)\approx x$ do
$$z'=\begin{pmatrix}z_1\\z_2 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x''\\ x'\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-2\alpha&-\alpha^2\\ 2\alpha&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x'\\ x\end{pmatrix}$$
but this seems wrong too. How do I do this?#

**So Yeah turns out I read system as linear system so that's that**

Comment: The equation is nonlinear. You can't turn it into a linear system, if that's what you were trying to do

Comment: Ya i figured it out; gg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $y(t):=x'(t)$ and

$$\begin{cases}x'(t)=y(t),\\y'(t)=-2\alpha y(t)-\alpha^2\sin(x(t))\end{cases}$$ is your system.